# Void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On the beginning: i tried all solutions here.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.justfashion, PID: 5068
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.justfashion/com.justfashion.ActivityMainWallet}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

ActivityMainWallet.java with error lines:

```
drawerToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.drawer_toolbar);
    drawerToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    drawerToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    drawerToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

Main layout XML:
http://pastebin.com/4UjqqZUk

Thanks a lot guys!

### EDIT

I've got now in my java file:

```
  drawerToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarInner);
    drawerToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    drawerToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    drawerToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openAndCloseDrawer();
        }
    });
```

And also in toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarInner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Widget.Toolbar.Title"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Widget.Toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Also in main xml layout nothing changed. **The same error.** Help me!

Comment: Have you verified that drawerToolbar isn't null after findViewById() ?

Comment: Where is the id `drawer_toolbar` in your XML? Couldn't see on xml layout link provided?

Comment: @MarkKeen i''ve got only toolbar.xml:
http://pastebin.com/JrXBFbwy

Comment: @user2393513 and same question : where is the id drawer_toolbar in your toolbar.xml ?

Comment: @FrédéricLetellier It will be the same when I will copy the content from toolbar.xml, change id from toolbar to drawer_toolbar and save it as draver_toolbar? Or I will need to change something in java file?

Comment: Your id is wrong in your layout it is: `toolbarInner` not `drawer_toolbar` ? Change the id reference in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
drawerToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarInner);

should under the setContentView(R.layout.your_loayout);
```

because otherwise `findViewById()` don't know how to find `R.id.toolbarInner`
or which file to find.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear enough :

> Void
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' **on
>   a null object reference**

The id `drawer_toolbar` isn't in your provided file :
 - toolbar.xml: [pastebin.com/JrXBFbwy](http://pastebin.com/JrXBFbwy)

The toolbar id in your java file `ActivityMainWallet.java` and the toolbar id in your xml file `toolbar.xml` **need to be the same**.

Comment: See my comment about IDs in the original question looks like simple wrong id reference

Comment: @MarkKeen Yes, we agree on this problem and its answer

Comment: @FrédéricLetellier so toolbar.xml have to be like that?
http://pastebin.com/dwyFmmdV

Comment: @user2393513 Yes and in this case, don't modified java file. Can you try ? And say if it's ok ?

Comment: @FrédéricLetellier my toolbar.xml now is: http://pastebin.com/FfPHkFHw

And i'm getting the same error.

Comment: @user2393513 Why you declare two toolbars ?!? Delete the first toolbar with `toolbarInner` id

Comment: @FrédéricLetellier 'cause in my activity is toolbarInner too. How to make it?

Comment: @user2393513 In this case, in toolbar.xml delete the second toolbar with `drawer_toolbar`. And in your java file, change the line `drawerToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.drawer_toolbar);` by `drawerToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarInner);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126769/discussion-between-user2393513-and-frederic-letellier).

Comment: @MarkKeen check the edit. I made all changes and the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#344955"
        >
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now you have to include a layout in your XML file as follow

**activity_user_data.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#356859"
    tools:context=".UserDataActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, finally, in your java file, you have to simply follow some simple steps

```
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("User's Data");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find drawer_toolbar in your layout file. Try to inlude it and after you can set title on it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.